# I want to update a field when a checkbox is checked on VF page

Tags: javascript, visualforce, apex

I am customizing Account Edit page. So I created a Edit VF page for Account, on this VF page I am bringing all the contacts which has same owner ID as current Account on Edit VF page. like below

[IMAGE LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOQF8.gif)

So i want to write a javascript function when the checkbox is checked I want to update the Text custom field with contact name and users should be able to choose one contact not more than that.

**I don't have much knowledge about javascript please help me with this**

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this.

```js
function writeChanges(element) {
  document.getElementById("customfield").value = element.getAttribute("myName");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" myName="Name 1" onchange="writeChanges(this)"/> Name 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" myName="Name 2" onchange="writeChanges(this)"/> Name 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" myName="Name 3" onchange="writeChanges(this)"/> Name 3
<br /><br /><br />
<input type="text" id="customfield" />
```

Comment: Your code is not working for <apex:inputfield/> I want that field to get updated

Comment: you need to change the names in the javascript. i did not know how the IDs in your html looks like. the code is only a small sample how you are maybe able to get it done. without some code i am not able to do more.